# File I/O. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. How to solve this?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read "test.txt", which only contains one line: "20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10", and wanted to print out the value if it's even.

The code got me the answer, but also shows ValueError:

20
18
16
14
12
10

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      3     val=val.split(" ")
      4     for i in val:
----> 5         if int(i)%2==0:
      6             print(i)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Please advise how to solve this. Thanks!

Code as below:

```
    val=infile.read()
    val=val.split(" ")
    for i in val:
        if int(i)%2==0:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Try `val=val.strip().split(" ")` as you're probably picking up a stray '\n' from your input file.

Comment: Or just `val = val.split()`, to get all the non-whitespace groups.

Comment: Thanks so much! val = val.split() works perfect! Why does it make a difference though?To my best knowledge, split()'s default setting ia split(' ')??